# Spinner - How to get value? Android Studio

Tags: android, spinner

I would like to insert values from a form into my database. I had problems with values from spinners and I did something wrong, because when I intent in my next activity where the form is the app stops. I will be really grateful.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

`EditText UsernameEt, PasswordEt;`

```
private static Button btnLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    UsernameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    PasswordEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    OnClickButtonListener();


}
public void OnClickButtonListener() {
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(".SecondPan");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}



public void OnLogin(View view)
{
    String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
    String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type,username,password);


}
public void OpenReg(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(this,Register.class));
}
```

`}`

Second Panel where user should've been intented and where spinners are:

```
public class SecondPan extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private Spinner sspnOption6, sspn2;
private TextView ttxOption6, ttx;
EditText umowa,nazwa,kategorie,opis,zabezpieczenia,dane;
String czy_dane, transfer;



@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_pan);

    Spinner sspn2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sspn);
     czy_dane = sspn2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Spinner sspnOption6 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sspn2);
     transfer = sspnOption6.getSelectedItem().toString();


    umowa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_txt1);
    nazwa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_txt2);
    kategorie = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_txt3);
    opis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_tx4);
    zabezpieczenia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_tx6);
    dane = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_tx7);


    sspnOption6 = findViewById(R.id.sspn);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> FirstAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.tab1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    FirstAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    sspn2=findViewById(R.id.sspn2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> Secondadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.transfer, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    Secondadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sspn2.setAdapter(Secondadapter);


}
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
    String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void OnInsert(View view ) {
    String str_czy_dane = sspn2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String str_umowa = umowa.getText().toString();
    String str_nazwa = nazwa.getText().toString();
    String str_kategorie = kategorie.getText().toString();
    String str_opis = opis.getText().toString();
    String str_transfer  = sspn2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String str_zabezpieczenia = zabezpieczenia.getText().toString();
    String str_dane = dane.getText().toString();
    String type = "insert";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, str_czy_dane,str_umowa, str_nazwa, str_kategorie, str_opis,str_transfer, str_zabezpieczenia, str_dane);
}
```

}

And there is a script to POST data:
BackgroundWorker.java

```
else if(type.equals("insert")){
        try {
            String umowa = params[1];
            String czy_dane = params[2];
            String nazwa = params[3];
            String kategorie = params[4];
            String opis = params[5];
            String transfer = params[6];
            String zabezpieczenia = params[7];
            String dane = params[8];

            URL url = new URL (insert_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("czy_dane","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(czy_dane,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("umowa","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(umowa,"UTF-8")+"&"
            +URLEncoder.encode("nazwa","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(nazwa,"UTF-8")+"&"
            +URLEncoder.encode("kategorie","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(kategorie,"UTF-8")+"&"
            +URLEncoder.encode("opis","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(opis,"UTF-8")+"&"
            +URLEncoder.encode("transfer","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(transfer,"UTF-8")+"&"
            +URLEncoder.encode("zabezpieczenia","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(zabezpieczenia,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("dane","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(dane,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1")) ;
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
                result+= line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    return null;
```

Comment: What error do you get? can you post your crash report please?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are twice assigning Spinner.

```
Spinner sspn2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sspn); /// FIRST SPINNER 1 time
czy_dane = sspn2.getSelectedItem().toString();

Spinner sspnOption6 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sspn2);/// SECOND SPINNER 1 time
transfer = sspnOption6.getSelectedItem().toString();


    umowa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_txt1);
    nazwa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_txt2);
    kategorie = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_txt3);
    opis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_tx4);
    zabezpieczenia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_tx6);
    dane = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_tx7);


sspnOption6 = findViewById(R.id.sspn); /// FIRST SPINNER 2 time


ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> FirstAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.tab1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    FirstAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

sspn2=findViewById(R.id.sspn2);   /// SECOND SPINNER 2 time



ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> Secondadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.transfer, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    Secondadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sspn2.setAdapter(Secondadapter);
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
Spinner sspn2 ; 

Spinner sspnOption6 ; 

    umowa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_txt1);
    nazwa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_txt2);
    kategorie = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_txt3);
    opis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_tx4);
    zabezpieczenia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_tx6);
    dane = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scnd_tx7);


sspnOption6 = findViewById(R.id.sspn); 
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> FirstAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources()
                .getStringArray(R.array.tab1));
                FirstAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sspnOption6.setAdapter(FirstAdapter);
    
    
sspn2=findViewById(R.id.sspn2);  
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> Secondadapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources()
                .getStringArray(R.array.transfer));
                Secondadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);   
sspn2.setAdapter(Secondadapter);
    
    
    czy_dane = sspn2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    transfer = sspnOption6.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: "Logging keeps stopping" it is when I press login button and I want to intent to the second panel :( I've already deleted but still doesn't work :/ I can only app again, that's all.

Comment: Please review the above once again you are assigning twice for each of the two spinners.

Comment: Thanks a lot it intented me! You've already saved my life. I have some troubles now with data insert but I think I'll solve it!

Comment: Good . Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot one more time friend.

Comment: Friend, can you take a look in this code and may you can say what's wrong :/ I still can't add values. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't add values to Spinners?

Comment: I have modified solution part in Answer. Please try.

Comment: Thanks for reply, unfortunately app still stopps after submit. PHP script is okay, because when I open it on localhost with set values they're inserted correctly to database. No idea what's wrong but I will work on it.